# How can I loop through a list of dicts and compare the value of a key and make changes with it

Tags: networking, automation, ansible, cisco

I am looping through a series of switches checking if they have the vlans which the firewall has, and change the 'name' key to equal the 'alias' key on the switches.

This is what I have so far. The last part is where I think my problem lies.

```
 ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 - name: Sync VLAN names according to FortiGate alias
   hosts: test_switches, fortigate
   gather_facts: false
   connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
   tasks:

   #Grab VLAN information from vlan interfaces that have an alias
   - name: Gather information from Fortigate
     delegate_to: fortigate
     connection: httpapi
     fortinet.fortios.fortios_configuration_fact:
       filters:
         - vlanid!=0
         - alias!=""
       formatters:
         - name
         - alias
         - vlanid
         - ip
       sorters:
         - vlanid
       selector: system_interface
     register: out
     vars:
       ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: yes
       ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: no
       ansible_httpapi_port: 443
       vdom: "root"
     run_once: true
   #Gather vlan information from IOS devices
   - name: Print info (ios)
     cisco.ios.ios_vlans:
       state: gathered
     when: ansible_network_os == "cisco.ios.ios"
     register: vlanIOS

   # Gather vlan information from NXOS devices
   - name: Print info (nxos)
     cisco.nxos.nxos_vlans:
       state: gathered
     when: ansible_network_os == "cisco.nxos.nxos"
     register: vlanNXOS

   #Loop through vlan interfaces & loop through each device's VLANs, comparing
   #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   - name: Set information
     debug:
     msg: "{{item.alias}} with VLAN ID {{item.vlanid}} is in this switch"
     loop: "{{ hostvars['firewall'].out.meta.results }}"
     when: "(ansible_network_os == 'cisco.ios.ios' or ansible_network_os == 'cisco.nxos.nxos') and item.vlanid in (vlanIOS.gathered | map(attribute='vlan_id'))"
```

I am comparing the vlanid of this

```
{
                "alias": "STREAMING_SRVS",
                "ip": "10.112.81.1 255.255.255.192",
                "name": "DMZ_01",
                "q_origin_key": "DMZ_01",
                "vlanid": 781
            }
```

with the vlan_id from this.

```
{
            "mtu": 1500,
            "name": "default",
            "shutdown": "disabled",
            "state": "active",
            "vlan_id": 1
        }
```

These examples are part 2 separate lists respectively.

With my code I am able to figure out if the VLAN is in the switch, but I would like to know which VLAN it is and be able to change it accordingly. Could I be able to do this? I am fairly new to ansible.

Comment: Please make sure to provide a **valid** [mre]. The line number as well as an obvious typo with a missing dash in front of the last `debug` task makes the code you are producing in your question invalid.

Comment: Edited question with my full code.